# On characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $A,B\subset X$. Can we consider $\mid\chi_A-\chi_B\mid$ as a characteristic function of some subset of $X$? If yes which subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply $\chi_{A \bigtriangleup B}=|\chi_A-\chi_B|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answering.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, it seems your function takes $1$ iff exactly one of $\chi_A, \chi_B$ is equal to $1$, so I would say $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$?

Answer (score 1):

It is the characteristic function of the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) $A \triangle B$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answering.

Answer (score 1):

In this context the fact that the function only takes values in $\{0,1\}$ is *enough* to conclude that it is indeed the characteristic function of some subset of $X$.

The other answers mention the subset in question.